# Syntax choices for accessing child objects

Tags: php, syntax, object, static, syntactic-sugar

I'm wondering which is semantically and technically most optimal of my choices here. I've created a simple object registry class, but the method of object access has me wondering what's best. I'm currently using the first variation:

```
//the Registry methods can chain, each returning a self reference
$registry = Registry::getInstance()->register('myObject', new Object);

//accessing a registered object method
//in various possible ways
Registry::getInstance()->myObject->method();        //1
Registry::getInstance()->use('myObject')->method(); //2
$registry('myObject')->method();                    //3
```

- The first variation uses `__get()` magic, keeping with the fluent syntax.
- The second uses the '*getter*' method `use()`.
- The third uses `__invoke()` magic, which has been suggested, but I am not too fond of.

I'm just curious to know if anyone has insight, or suggestions towards using any (or none) of these options. The reason for using a Registry class in my case is to provide pseudo-globalization of key objects, for use in nested closures (declaring them with `use` every time is cumbersome)

This is somewhat related to my other question, at [PHP closures and implicit global variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054424/php-closures-and-implicit-global-variable-scope)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Another option that would be quite nice would be to implement the ArrayAccess interface so you could use `$registry['myObject']->method();`.  For efficiency however, you would want to cache `myObject` if you were going to perform multiple operations on it e.g. `$myObject = $registry['myObject'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal opinion is to Use a combination of your 2nd and 3rd code-example. Using both (or only your 2nd example) you can use phpDoc to maintain autocompletion.

Here's an example:

```
<?php

class Session {
    public function register() {
    }
}

/**
 * @property Session $session
 */
class Registry {
    private $_classes = array();

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $key = (string) $key;
        if ((null === $value) && isset($this->_classes[$key])) {
            unset($this->_classes[$key]);
        } elseif (null !== $value) {
            $this->_classes[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        $key = (string) $key;
        if (isset($this->_classes[$key])) {
            return $this->_classes[$key];
        }

        switch ($key) {
            case 'session':
                $this->_classes[$key] = new Session();
                break;
        }

        return $this->_classes[$key];
    }
}

$registry = new Registry();
$registry->session->register();
```

If I should give you a hint why my Registry-class does not follow the singleton-pattern ... avoid using the singleton-pattern if you want to run unit-tests. See here: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html